# Laravel 8 | Fortify with MustVerifyEmail after user registers redirects to login page instead of show "must verify email" view

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel 8 + Fortify + Jetstream and I have selected the option to verify email after registration. The problem is that when the user completes the registration form, laravel redirects to the login page instead of showing the view with the message "You must verify your email before you can login"

My User model implements MustVerifyEmail contract, and the strange situation is that this is working fine on local valet environment but not in the real web server.

I must say that despite not showing the message, the email with the verification link is sent correctly and also, the link works, adding the verification date in the user table. But here there is also another flaw and that is that it does not show the message "your email has been verified and now you can log in" but it directly shows the login screen.

Another strange situation that I consider related to the previous ones is that if I try to login without doing the email verification, the login fails without any message. Just redirecting again to login form

This is my relevant code and configuration

App\Models\User

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Fortify\TwoFactorAuthenticatable;
use Laravel\Jetstream\HasProfilePhoto;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\MediaCollections\Models\Media;
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\HasMedia;
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\InteractsWithMedia;
use App\Http\Traits\Uuids;


class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail, HasMedia
{

}
```

config/fortify

```
<?php
...
'features' => [
        Features::registration(),
        Features::resetPasswords(),
        Features::emailVerification(),
        Features::updateProfileInformation(),
        Features::updatePasswords(),
        Features::twoFactorAuthentication([
            'confirmPassword' => true,
        ]),
    ],
```

Any ideas will be highly appreciated. Regards.

Comment: I am discovering some things. The verification message is shown only if the user is logged in, through the /email/verify route. But I have detected that what is failing is the login mechanism, because already validated users when they try to enter they always return to the login form without error message

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a solution for this issue by investigating the side of error 419.

In my configuration (.env) I had set  `SESSION_DRIVER=database`,
in principle I changed that value to `SESSION_DRIVER=file` and it did not work either.

I also controlled the write permissions of the folder storage and all its dependent folders, with no results.
Seeing that the `.env` file also had `SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE=true` defined, which sounds reasonable to me because the site in production uses https, I decided to try changing to `SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE=false` and then the session was saved correctly.

I am still trying to understand why it worked this way, but in principle it is very important for me to have found a solution for this problem. I hope that this experience should helps somebody.